# Pandoc rules regarding LaTeX not followed on R blogdown hugo themes

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, hugo, blogdown

I can create a new blogdown site utilizing the default [hugo-lithium](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium) theme and the text statement below will not render as a LaTeX equation, which is the behavior I expect.

`An amount between $5 and $10.`

[Pandoc's manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math) explains the reason why, which I'll paste below with a bold emphasis:

> Anything between two `$` characters will be treated as TeX math. The opening `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its right, **while the closing `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its left, and must not be followed immediately by a digit**. Thus, `$20,000 and $30,000` won’t parse as math. If for some reason you need to enclose text in literal `$` characters, backslash-escape them and they won’t be treated as math delimiters.

HOWEVER, I can change to other Hugo themes (e.g. [hugo-theme-codex](https://github.com/jakewies/hugo-theme-codex)) and this exact same text block renders improperly whenever I include `math: true` in my YAML.

`An amount between $5 and $10.` ends up displaying as:

[image: latex and rmd]

Why is LaTeX invoked, when Pandoc is supposed to follow the rule I quoted above? How can I use "other" hugo themes, still use LaTeX math equations, and have Pandoc follow it's own rules? Escaping the `$` unfortunately doesn't do anything, and displays the same result as the un-escaped version.

```
# Doesn't work
An amount between \$5 and \$10.
```

[image: latex and rmd]

Getting in on the double slash escape action doesn't seem to work either:

```
# Doesn't work
An amount between \\$5 and \\$10.
```

[image: double slash image]

---

And for those wondering - the last two questions have been answered, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917217/r-markdown-inline-latex-equations-vs), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915849/cant-escape-latex-dollar-sign-in-blogdown), and if this question is answered this should be the end of this three part story.

Comment: What version of pandoc are you using?

Comment: @ekstroem `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` yields `'2.7.3'` which is about a year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the following file:

```
/your-blogdown-site/themes/hugo-theme-codex/layouts/partials/math.html
```

Then add this to the body of `math.html` that you just created:

```
<script src="//yihui.org/js/math-code.js"></script>
<script async
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

Only MathJax release `2.7.5` seems to work right.

The [blogdown book templates section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html) is a good source of reading material for this sort of thing. You must include `math: true` in your YAML to display LaTeX math equations utilizing this method.